# Hackerrank Staircase solution not accepted

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

A hackerrank [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase) demands you to print a staircase out of hashes:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

I've submitted the following code:

```
n = int(input())
for i in reversed(range(n)):
    print(i*' ','#'*(n-i))
```

It wasn't accepted. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) function prints its arguments separated by a space character (`" "`) by default, giving you extra characters in the output. You need to either `print` a single argument, or pass `sep=""`:

```
 print(i*' ' + '#'*(n-i))
```

or

```
 print(i*' ', '#'*(n-i), sep="")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your print statement.

```
print(i*' ','#'*(n-i))
```

If you print multiple strings separated by a comma, you will get the strings delimited by a space character. E.g.

```
>>> print("foo", "bar")
foo bar
>>> print("foo"+"bar")
foobar
```

You can combine two strings with the `+` operator.

Making this small change in your program should solve the problem.